# Implement cancelRequest

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip, cancel-button

I am implementing cancelRequest for ongoing call. I try to send Request once the session is established. the cancel function worked the first time I implemented it but now it says transaction exists. How do I fix it?

```
else if(currentREsponse.equals("Session Progress")){
            System.out.println("------------------- Status Code: "+ statusCode+ "--------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse());
            try {

                Request cancelRequest;
                cancelRequest = inviteTid.createCancel();
                ClientTransaction canceltid = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(cancelRequest);
                canceltid.sendRequest();
                System.out.println("Cancel Requst:" + cancelRequest);
            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
```

Response:

```
-----------StatusCode:100----------------------------
-----------currentREsponse:Trying----------------------------
------------------- Status Code: 100--------------------------
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-353435-03dc537ef691bb00e1e5512b034ea431;received=localIP;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-2016245219
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Call-ID: fab08b0be8c74b236c9eced419dec3ae@localIP
CSeq: 5 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Length: 0


------------------- Phone is RINGING hangup --------------------------


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
-----------StatusCode:183----------------------------
-----------currentREsponse:Session Progress----------------------------
------------------- Status Code: 183--------------------------
SIP/2.0 183 Session Progress
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-353435-03dc537ef691bb00e1e5512b034ea431;received=localIP;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-2016245219
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as06d748b5
Call-ID: fab08b0be8c74b236c9eced419dec3ae@localIP
CSeq: 5 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 254

v=0
o=root 16865513 16865513 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 16188 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

Cancel Requst:CANCEL sip:86940160@sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: fab08b0be8c74b236c9eced419dec3ae@localIP
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
CSeq: 5 CANCEL
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-2016245219
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-353435-32ce00c8a1c2efc96caa44a14bf3b910
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0




Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
-----------StatusCode:401----------------------------
-----------currentREsponse:Unauthorized----------------------------
---------------UNAUTHORIZED--------SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-353435-32ce00c8a1c2efc96caa44a14bf3b910;received=localIP;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-2016245219
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as647be936
Call-ID: fab08b0be8c74b236c9eced419dec3ae@localIP
CSeq: 5 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="69e1f4c2"
Content-Length: 0


-----------StatusCode:481----------------------------
-----------currentREsponse:Call/Transaction Does Not Exist----------------------------
-------------------Status Code: 481 ----------------------
SIP/2.0 481 Call/Transaction Does Not Exist
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.99.136.131:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-353435-32ce00c8a1c2efc96caa44a14bf3b910;received=10.99.136.131;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-2016245219
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as647be936
Call-ID: fab08b0be8c74b236c9eced419dec3ae@10.99.136.131
CSeq: 5 CANCEL
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Content-Length: 0


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
```

ProcessResponse

```
public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int statusCode = responseEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode();
        String currentResponse = responseEvent.getResponse().getReasonPhrase();
//      System.out.println("-----------StatusCode:"+ statusCode+"----------------------------");
//      System.out.println("-----------currentREsponse:"+ currentResponse+"----------------------------");
        CSeqHeader cseqtemp = (CSeqHeader) responseEvent.getResponse().getHeader(CSeqHeader.NAME);          
//      System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse().toString());

        System.out.println("................cseq" + cseqtemp);
        if(cseqtemp.getMethod().equals(Request.REGISTER)){
            processRegisterResponse(responseEvent);
        }else if(cseqtemp.getMethod().equals(Request.INVITE)){

            countInviteResponse ++;
            System.out.println(".....countInviteResponse: "+ countInviteResponse+" ......" );

            if(countInviteResponse == 6){
                System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse());
//              functions.cancel(responseEvent.getResponse());
            }
            try {
                processInviteResponse(responseEvent);
            } catch (SipException | InvalidArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("-------------------Status Code: "+ statusCode+" ----------------------");
            System.out.println(responseEvent.getResponse().toString());
        }
```

ProcessInvite Response:

```
private void processInviteResponse(ResponseEvent responseReceivedEvent) throws SipException, InvalidArgumentException {
        int statusCode = responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode();
        String currentResponse = responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().getReasonPhrase();
        Response response = responseReceivedEvent.getResponse();
        ClientTransaction tid = responseReceivedEvent.getClientTransaction();
        CSeqHeader cseqtemp = (CSeqHeader) response.getHeader(CSeqHeader.NAME);
        if(statusCode> 400 && statusCode <410){
            if((statusCode ==401 && cseqtemp.getMethod().equals(Request.INVITE))
                    || response.getStatusCode() == Response.PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED){
                System.out.println(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().toString());
//              if(functions.cseq<4){

                    System.out.println("------------------Invite 401--------------------\n");

                    AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = 
                            ((SipStackExt) functions.sipStack).getAuthenticationHelper(new AccountManagerImpl(), functions.headerFactory);
                    try {
                        functions.inviteTid = authenticationHelper.handleChallenge(response, functions.inviteTid, functions.sipProvider, 5);
                        functions.inviteTid.sendRequest();
                        System.out.println("/n" + functions.inviteTid.getRequest());
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SipException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//                  functions.call(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse());
//              }
            }
        }else if(statusCode == 200){
            try {
                System.out.println(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().toString());

                response = (Response) responseReceivedEvent.getResponse();
                tid = responseReceivedEvent.getClientTransaction();
                CSeqHeader cseq = (CSeqHeader) response.getHeader(CSeqHeader.NAME);     
                Dialog dialog = responseReceivedEvent.getDialog();


                if (tid == null) {
                    // RFC3261: MUST respond to every 2xx
                    if (ackRequest!=null && dialog!=null) {
                        System.out.println("re-sending ACK");
                        dialog.sendAck(ackRequest);
                    }
                    return;
                }

                if (response.getStatusCode() == Response.OK) {
                    System.out.println("Dialog after 200 OK  " + dialog);
                    System.out.println("Dialog State after 200 OK  " + dialog.getState());
                    ackRequest = dialog.createAck(cseq.getSeqNumber() );
                    System.out.println("Sending ACK");
                    dialog.sendAck(ackRequest);
                }



                }
             catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else if(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().getReasonPhrase().equals("Trying")){
            System.out.println("------------------- Status Code: "+ statusCode+ "--------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse());


        }else if(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().getReasonPhrase().equals("Ringing")){
            System.out.println("------------------- Status Code: "+ statusCode+ "--------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse());
            System.out.println("------------------- Phone is RINGING --------------------------");


        }else if(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse().getReasonPhrase().equals("Session Progress")){
            System.out.println("------------------- Status Code: "+ statusCode+ "--------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse());
//          functions.cancel(response);

            Request cancelRequest= responseReceivedEvent.getClientTransaction().createCancel();

            functions.sipProvider.sendRequest(cancelRequest);
            System.out.println(cancelRequest.toString());
        }else {
            System.out.println("------------------- Status Code: "+ statusCode+ "--------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseReceivedEvent.getResponse());
        }


    }
```

Invite:

```
public void call(Response response) {
        try {
            Request request;
            cseq++;
            String callee = "86940160";
//          String callee = "160";
            current_process = cseq + "INVITE";
            ArrayList viaHeaders = new ArrayList();
            ViaHeader viaHeader = headerFactory.createViaHeader(localIP,
                    rport, "udp", null);
            viaHeader.setRPort();
            viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
            // The "Max-Forwards" header.
            MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = headerFactory.createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
            // The "Call-Id" header.
            CallIdHeader callIdHeader;

            if(!retry){
                callIdHeader = this.sipProvider.getNewCallId();
                callIdHeaderinit = callIdHeader;
            }else{
                callIdHeader = callIdHeaderinit;
            }

            // The "CSeq" header.
            CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(cseq, Request.INVITE);

            Address fromAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:"
                    + username + '@' + server);

            Address toAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:"+callee+'@'+sipIP);

            FromHeader fromHeader = headerFactory.createFromHeader(
                    fromAddress, String.valueOf(this.tag));
            // The "To" header.
            ToHeader toHeader = headerFactory.createToHeader(toAddress,
                    null);

         // Create the contact address used for all SIP messages.
            contactAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:" + username + "@"+ localIP +":"+rport+ ";"+ "transport=UDP");

            // Create the contact header used for all SIP messages.
            contactHeader = headerFactory.createContactHeader(contactAddress);

            ContentLengthHeader contentLength = headerFactory.createContentLengthHeader(211);
            ContentTypeHeader contentType = headerFactory.createContentTypeHeader("application", "sdp");

            String sdpData = "v=0\n" + 
                    "o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 "+localIP+"\n" + 
                    "s=-\n" + 
                    "c=IN IP4 "+localIP+"\n" + 
                    "t=0 0\n" + 
                    "m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101\n" + 
                    "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\n" + 
                    "a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\n" + 
                    "a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\n" + 
                    "a=sendrecv";
             byte[] contents = sdpData.getBytes();
//           this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory
//           .createContactHeader(contactAddress);

             URI requestURI = addressFactory.createURI("sip:"
                    +callee+ '@'+ server); 

            request = messageFactory.createRequest(requestURI, Request.INVITE, 
                    callIdHeader,cSeqHeader, fromHeader, toHeader, viaHeaders, maxForwardsHeader);

            request.setContent(contents, contentType);

            request.addHeader(contactHeader);
            request.addHeader(contentLength);

            if (response != null) {
                AuthorizationHeader authHeader = null;

                if(retry){
                    authHeader = getAuthorizationHeader();
                    retry = false;
                }else{
                    authHeader = makeAuthHeader(headerFactory, response, request, username, password);
                    retry = true;
                }
                request.addHeader(authHeader);
//              AuthenticationHelper authenticationHelper = 
//                      ((SipStackExt) sipStack).getAuthenticationHelper(new AccountManagerImpl(), headerFactory);
//              try {
//                  inviteTid = authenticationHelper.handleChallenge(response, tid, sipProvider, 5);
//                  inviteTid.sendRequest();
//              } catch (NullPointerException e) {
//                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              } catch (SipException e) {
//                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                  e.printStackTrace();
//              }
            }

//          ExpiresHeader expiresHeader = headerFactory.createExpiresHeader(1);
//   
//          request.addHeader(expiresHeader);

//          test listener =this;
            if (response != null) {
                boolean retry = true;
//              System.out.println("DEBUG: Response: "+response);

            }
            inviteTid = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);


            if(dialog!= null && logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug("Obtain dialog from ClientTransaction: automatic dialog support on");
//              System.out.println("Obtain dialog from ClientTransaction: automatic dialog support on");
            }
            if(dialog == null){
                //Automatic Dialog support turned off

                dialog = sipProvider.getNewDialog(inviteTid);

            }
            System.out.println("Dialog: created" + dialog);
            // send the request out.
            inviteTid.sendRequest();

            dialog = inviteTid.getDialog();
//          System.out.println("Dialog:" + dialog);

            // Send the request statelessly through the SIP provider.
            // this.sipProvider.sendRequest(request);
            System.out.println(request.toString());
            // Display the message in the text area.
            logger.debug("Request sent:\n" + "\n\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If an error occurred, display the error.
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.debug("Request sent failed: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Response:

```
REGISTER sip:sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: cdf4ef0fa1a145b1b07b632797f53fdb@localIP
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-1436906198
To: <sip:username@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-3230-3d42d8c86f8aa3d6d0194a4846511464
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:52216;transport=UDP>
Content-Length: 0


log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (test).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
................cseqCSeq: 1 REGISTER

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-3230-3d42d8c86f8aa3d6d0194a4846511464;received=localIP;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-1436906198
To: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=as24ab6bcf
Call-ID: cdf4ef0fa1a145b1b07b632797f53fdb@localIP
CSeq: 1 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="6ac7ff34"
Content-Length: 0


REGISTER sip:sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: cdf4ef0fa1a145b1b07b632797f53fdb@localIP
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-1436906198
To: <sip:username@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-3230-a94c094a3aacfc40d0455de777b0ae26
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:52216;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="6ac7ff34",uri="sip:sipIP",algorithm=MD5,response="53231e4a2cd26604d8d2bc867b0e43e9"
Content-Length: 0


................cseqCSeq: 2 REGISTER

---------------------------Registered: 200--------------------

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-3230-a94c094a3aacfc40d0455de777b0ae26;received=localIP;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-1436906198
To: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=as24ab6bcf
Call-ID: cdf4ef0fa1a145b1b07b632797f53fdb@localIP
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Expires: 240
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:52216;transport=UDP>;expires=240
Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2015 14:46:46 GMT
Content-Length: 0


Dialog: createdgov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPDialog@79f65165
INVITE sip:86940160@sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: cdf4ef0fa1a145b1b07b632797f53fdb@localIP
CSeq: 3 INVITE
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-1436906198
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-3230-c5512f65af9890c0798f1e5757ef1c57
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:username@localIP:52216;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="6ac7ff34",uri="sip:sipIP",algorithm=MD5,response="53231e4a2cd26604d8d2bc867b0e43e9"
Content-Length: 211

v=0
o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 localIP
s=-
c=IN IP4 localIP
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
................cseqCSeq: 3 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 1 ......
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-3230-c5512f65af9890c0798f1e5757ef1c57;received=localIP;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-1436906198
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as43ee81b7
Call-ID: cdf4ef0fa1a145b1b07b632797f53fdb@localIP
CSeq: 3 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="6ad3bcf0"
Content-Length: 0
```

Response after removing Tag:

```
------------------Invite 401--------------------

/nINVITE sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 7128d7fc7109b0c1293dce9f6b2b9c7b@localIP.131
CSeq: 4 INVITE
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-515507368
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP.131:52216;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-313339-453b043ba57ac51c5293cf17f8823071
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:username@localIP.131:52216;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="3cdd5016",uri="sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP",response="38b50cad69f74ba89fd63f78a1968acc",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 211

v=0
o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 localIP.131
s=-
c=IN IP4 localIP.131
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv


Request OPTIONSreceived at stackwith server transaction idnull
................cseqCSeq: 4 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 2 ......
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP.131:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-313339-453b043ba57ac51c5293cf17f8823071;received=localIP.131;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-515507368
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as5f585fd4
Call-ID: 7128d7fc7109b0c1293dce9f6b2b9c7b@localIP.131
CSeq: 4 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5,realm="xyz.com",nonce="6aa75c9f"
Content-Length: 0


------------------Invite 401--------------------

/nINVITE sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 7128d7fc7109b0c1293dce9f6b2b9c7b@localIP.131
CSeq: 5 INVITE
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-515507368
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP.131:52216;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-313339-5ed3ab3afc3b791c0af19470ae58813d
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Contact: <sip:username@localIP.131:52216;transport=UDP>
Authorization: Digest username="username",realm="xyz.com",nonce="6aa75c9f",uri="sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP",response="092fc083a66f19b5b995c8cbc8d5a8bc",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 211

v=0
o=user1 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 localIP.131
s=-
c=IN IP4 localIP.131
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
................cseqCSeq: 5 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 3 ......
------------------- Status Code: 100--------------------------
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP.131:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-313339-5ed3ab3afc3b791c0af19470ae58813d;received=localIP.131;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-515507368
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
Call-ID: 7128d7fc7109b0c1293dce9f6b2b9c7b@localIP.131
CSeq: 5 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Length: 0


................cseqCSeq: 5 INVITE

.....countInviteResponse: 4 ......
------------------- Status Code: 183--------------------------
SIP/2.0 183 Session Progress
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP.131:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-313339-5ed3ab3afc3b791c0af19470ae58813d;received=localIP.131;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-515507368
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as7fc2a07d
Call-ID: 7128d7fc7109b0c1293dce9f6b2b9c7b@localIP.131
CSeq: 5 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Contact: <sip:86940160@sipIP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 256

v=0
o=root 163700690 163700690 IN IP4 sipIP
s=Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
c=IN IP4 sipIP
t=0 0
m=audio 25036 RTP/AVP 8 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

Invite ID:z9hG4bK-313339-5ed3ab3afc3b791c0af19470ae58813d
CANCEL sip:86940160@sipIP:5060;maddr=sipIP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 7128d7fc7109b0c1293dce9f6b2b9c7b@localIP.131
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>
CSeq: 5 CANCEL
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-515507368
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP.131:52216;rport;branch=z9hG4bK-313339-5ed3ab3afc3b791c0af19470ae58813d
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0


................cseqCSeq: 5 CANCEL

-------------------Status Code: 481 ----------------------
SIP/2.0 481 Call/Transaction Does Not Exist
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIP.131:52216;branch=z9hG4bK-313339-5ed3ab3afc3b791c0af19470ae58813d;received=localIP.131;rport=52216
From: <sip:username@sipIP>;tag=-515507368
To: <sip:86940160@sipIP>;tag=as23aeabf5
Call-ID: 7128d7fc7109b0c1293dce9f6b2b9c7b@localIP.131
CSeq: 5 CANCEL
Server: Asterisk PBX 10.5.1
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: can you show the error or stacktrace?

Comment: do i have to add authorization for Cancel ?

Comment: i didn't make any change but it has stopped giving error Transaction already exists but is giving the error 481.

Comment: 481 Call/Transaction Does Not Exist : I am a little confused at what is wrong now. You tried it once and canceled it and then the second time it does not exist? That should be correct b/c you canceled. Right?

Comment: Yes. the first time I created the cancelRequest it worked and after that its not working anymore. Unfortunately I didn't check the the stacktrace the first time.

Comment: I figured out y it worked the first time. I ran it in debug mode. when I run the code in debug mode with the break point at canceltid.sendRequest() it works. but when i run the code it doesn't work.

Comment: could be..i am still checking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a Thread of 5 sec and now it works. Some how the firewall was delaying the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The INVITE transaction ID is different from the CANCEL transaction ID. INVITE is

> z9hG4bK-353435-03dc537ef691bb00e1e5512b034ea431

and the CANCEL is

> z9hG4bK-353435-32ce00c8a1c2efc96caa44a14bf3b910

They should be the same.

The right way to do CANCEL is to use the original invite transaction and use the provider

> cancelRequest = inviteClientTransaction.createCancel();
>   sipProvider.sendRequest(cancelRequest);

Comment: I tried it. I still have the same problem It runs in debug mode only.

Comment: the Id changes even though I use the same InviteID

Comment: somehow the branch Id changes for Trying and Session Progress and the cancel uses the branchID of Invite. should it be same?

Comment: Are you sending CANCEL as shown above? sipProvider.sendRequest(cancelRequest); Don't create a new transaction for CANCEL.

Comment: OK. You should post fresh code and logs, but I am 99% sure that you are canceling the INVITE transaction that got challenged as opposed to the INVITE transaction that is authenticated. You must have two different INVITE transactions, the first authenticates and dies. You must use the second one to create the CANCEL.

Comment: I have added the new logs under "Response in Run Mode with original invite Transaction"

Comment: In that case you clearly received a response SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized. You are not allowed to send CANCEL after you receive a final response. You are unauthorized because you don't WWW-Authenticate.

Comment: Hi adding WWW-authenticate to Invite didnt work for me, I had to use AuthenticationHelper. So i removed the WWW-authenticate, now I have added it back. I am adding the new log now. also my Code. I am removing the old logs

Comment: OK, keep it that way. Next thing that is wrong is the REGISTER and INVITE should use different Call-IDs and tags. Use one call ID for REGISTER and another for INVITE, same for tags.

Comment: Yes I realised it later and fixed it. Now the question I have is When i send request at AuthenticationHelper should it have same call Id or different. Right now its same and I still have the same error.

Comment: OK, remove the to tag for the CANCEL and if it still doesnt work post the logs again.

Comment: How do I remove the Tag?

Comment: ((ToHeader)cancelRequest.getHeader(ToHeader.NAME)).removeParameter("tag");

Comment: Also I forgot to add before it does not run in debug also anymore after I changed the CALL-IDs for Register and Invite.

Comment: Well the error response that you get has a To tag as23aeabf5 while the leg tag from the 183 is as7fc2a07d. So Asterisk is dealing with some ambiguity here. You must be having some extra legs on this call that are not shown in this log. Try to find where as23aeabf5 comes from. It could be some peculiarity with asterisk, so it's worth trying to go back to what worked and introduce delays here and there to rule that out.

Comment: I added a Thread of 5 sec and now it works. Some how the firewall was delaying the transaction.